# Showing Parent, Grandparent as dynamic select options in Child Custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, customization, custom-taxonomy

I have 5 post types in a hierarchial order i.e., Department > Journal > Volume > Issue > Article. I am looking to pop Parent and grand parent select fields dynamically in a child post type

example when I want to create a new volume, I need to select the department and based on that journals linked to that department in another select field. Similarly when I am creating an Issue, I should have the same select fields along with volume selection now.

On wordpress using Jet engine plugin, can we achieve this ? Please guide me through